# How to use the 'Mixed-Mode' approach (which uses both the 'e3' as well as the 'e4' API's) into an RCP Project

Tags: eclipse, dependency-injection, eclipse-rcp, e4, emf

I downloaded a sample project [here](https://github.com/fredrikattebrant/Simple-4x-RCP-app) from GitHub which uses the mixed mode of RCP development. Here in that project they access the 'e4' D.I feature into an existing 3.x RCP application.

I too tried the same approach for my 3.x RCP Application (which has my own .product file) but the Menu's (or parts) which I defined in the 'MyLegacyIDE.e4xmi' file are not getting reflected into the launched product and the UI (menus, views, parts etc..) remains same as in my Eclipse 3.x series. Nothing new happens when having the MyLegacyIDE.e4xmi file to my plugin project.

Also, I've made the 'applicationXMI' parameter to point to the XMI file which I'd defined in my plugin location like :

```
<extension
     id="product"
     point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
  <product
        application="com.ami.veb.ui.application"
        name="VeB - e4 Product">
     <property
           name="applicationXMI"
           value="MyLegacyIDE.e4xmi">
     </property>
  </product>
```

Suggestions will be appreciated !!

### ROOT CAUSE (for my problem):

While debugging, I found that my Application Model ("MyLegacyIDE.e4xmi") is not getting loaded properly by Eclipse.   In the following line (during loading of the Application Model ):

```
Resource applicationResource = loadResource(applicationDefinitionInstance); of ResourceHandler.java ['org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench' plugin]
```

applicationDefinitionInstance --> still points to the 'LegacyIDE.e4xmi' which is present under 'org.eclipse.ui.workbench' plugin and not to the XMI file ("MyLegacyIDE.e4xmi") which I'd defined in my plugin.xml file  .

( i.e.., value of 'applicationDefinitionInstance' is "platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/LegacyIDE.e4xmi" and not   "platform:/plugin/com.ami.veb.ui/MyLegacyIDE.e4xmi")

Please correct me if I went wrong anywhere.

Comment: Can you provide all of the relevant parts of your plugin.xml please? E.g., where your application is defined. Also, Have you tried simply using the sample RCP as a starting point, i.e., remove content you don't need and replace it with your own content?

Answer (score 2):

I missed to include Trimmed Window. After adding the Trimmed window into my LegacyIDE.e4xmi, my Eclipse 3.x RCP application is now capable of achieving the Mixed mode.

```
<children xsi:type="basic:TrimmedWindow" xmi:id="_qBUjQHb5EeWNbY4EJKhljA" elementId="com.ami.veb.ui.trimmedwindow.0"/>
```

Initially, I am in a wrong assumption that Trimmed Window is reqd. only if the entire layout is controlled by the application model (i.e.., only if I completely migrate to e4 Architecuture).

Later I observed that after adding this to my LegacyIDE.e4xmi file, I'm able to load the Application model into my 3.x Eclipse Workspace.

Comment: Even though now I'm able to load the application model into my 3.x Eclipse application. I'm not sure (I wonder) what Trimmed window has to do with the Mixed Mode. Actually all my RCP layout (views, menu etcc..,) are controlled by plugin.xml, why this Trimmed window is reqd. for even acheiving the mixed mode. - Just curious to know :)